# Why is infinity *infinity and infinity^infinity considered indeterminate?

Tags: limits, infinity, indeterminate-forms

I know that infinity is not a specific number,so we cannot apply normal algebric operations with it.But we can use the concepts of limits.So why is x^x or x*x (where x tends to infinity) indeterminate?Isn't it supposed to be infinity as in case of x+x?

Comment: Who says $\infty^\infty$ and $\infty\cdot \infty$ are indeterminate?

Comment: The book I refer "differential calculus by Amit M Aggarwal"says that both of them are indeterminate forms.

Comment: Ok.I think that I got the answer.It does not states using limits but actually uses equality.So that might be the reason of stating that indeterminate

Comment: "indeterminate" is not a good formulation because this is for cases where the limit is unknown without further informations, like "$0\cdot \infty$".